# "Too broad" question

Tags: support, asking-questions

I need to solve a problem related to rearranging items having various parameters to minimize time. This problem may be related to tags `combinatorics`, `algorithm`, `gantt-chart` etc. All I want is to get a direction where to move to. Is it possible to ask such question here without being marked "too broad"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that doesn't sound like a specific question at all.  Everything that you've described about it leads me to believe it would be Too Broad.  This is pretty much always going to be the case for a, "get me started" question.

Comment: Yep, "get me started...", "point me in the right direction...", "I'm lost..." type questions almost always are too broad.